# "com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value" with bitwise 'OR'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, bitwise-operators

I found a strange behavior when using the MySQL bitwise 'OR'. Help to understand the cause of this behavior.

For example: 
We create the table outOfRangeTest:

```
CREATE TABLE mttOutOfRangeTest (long_field  BIGINT NOT NULL);
```

Insert a negative number -1 in the table. The transaction is successful:

```
INSERT INTO mttOutOfRangeTest (long_field) VALUES (-1)
```

But when you try to use a bitwise 'OR' which return -1 occurs strange behavior.

```
long value1 = new BigInteger("0000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111", 2).longValue(); // 17179869183L
long value2 = new BigInteger("1111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000", 2).longValue(); // -17179869184L
long resultInJava = value1 | value2; // result = -1;
```

**If you update field via JDBC:**

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mttOutOfRangeTest (long_field) VALUES (?)");
pstmt.setLong(1, value1);
pstmt.executeUpdate();

pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE mttOutOfRangeTest SET long_field = (long_field | ?)");
pstmt.setLong(1, value2);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

There is an exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'long_field' at row 1

com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4230)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxyStatement.invoke(ProxyStatement.java:100)
org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxyStatement.intercept(ProxyStatement.java:57)
$java.sql.Statement$$EnhancerByProxool$$4b0edd73.executeUpdate(<generated>)
com.mtt.openfire.test.integration.db.OutOfRangeExceptionTest.testUpdateOutOfRange(OutOfRangeExceptionTest.java:78)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

**If you update field via MySql command line:**

```
INSERT INTO mttOutOfRangeTest (long_field) VALUES (17179869183);
UPDATE mttOutOfRangeTest SET long_field = (long_field | -17179869184);
```

Result is **9223372036854775807** (Max Long Value), but not **-1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OR operator `|` is for unsigned 64 bits integers. `-1L` falls out of that range. Evidently also the parameters must be unsigned. So do not use setLong, but maybe `setObject(... BigInteger ...)` or:

```
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(Long.MAX_VALUE); // 0111...111
n = n.multiply(BigDecimal.TWO).add(BigDecimal.ONE); // 111...111
pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, n);
```